"For more on that, see" - Is it correct to use "that" for multiple matters?
I write an academic paper and when I need to make a reference from one section to another to better explain something, I use the For more on that, see construction.

blah-blah-blah the gravitational expansion. For more on that, see the "Space, Gravity, and everything Einstein didn't tell us" section.

But what if I want to provide a link to better explain multiple conceptions and not just a single one? Is the word "that" still correct in such a case?

blah-blah-blah the gravitational expansion and the time shift. For more on [that? them? those?], see the "Space, Gravity, and everything Einstein didn't tell us" section.


If you are referring the reader to the same place for information on all of them, then it is OK, and probably preferable, to use that.
You would probably use them to refer to multiple subjects, if you want to refer the reader to different places for each subject.

... blah blah X, Y and Z. For more information them, refer to the appropriate chapter in ...

